# Is the Solr Query possible with function value comparison?

Tags: solr, indexing

I am working on solr for 3-4 months. I want to know if it is possible to query on solr with following requirements.
    ***return all the documents where,

    fieldName1 = queryTerm1 &

    strdist(queryTerm2, fieldName2, JW) > 5 (or some constant)***
If this is possible, what will be the query?

Comment: Please mention your use case, and why [Solr's spell check](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent) is inadequate.

Comment: But you can boost over string distance with [function queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#strdist).

Comment: Basically there are different clients with fieldName clientId, I want to pass all the documents of perticular client and perticular queryTerm (appearing in one of the text field with fieldName content) to next module. Solr indexing-stemming gives me lots of false positives, so i was thinking of going for strdist with JW (Jaro-Winkler) algorithm. I have tested accuracy of JW with java, it is fair enough but time consuming. I just wanted an efficient way that I guess solr can provide. Note that sign '>' and number '5' in the question are just for example.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can get close.

---

Sort the results on string distance (split for easier):

```
localhost:8983/solr/select/?fl=id
&q=fieldName1:queryTerm1
&sort=strdist("queryTerm2",fieldName2, JW)  desc
```

which will order the results, highest string distance downwards.

Note that you cannot **directly** get the string distance. There is a pseudo-field score, retrieved by:

```
fl=id,score
```

but it means nothing in an absolute sense.

---

You can also **boost** results based on the string distance, instead of simply sorting them. In this case, it will look at the relevancy of the document as well as the string distance.

---

Once you have a sorted list (hope its not too large!), you can determine **client-side** the elements which have 'string distance < 5'.

---

I made this up from the links below.

http://yonik.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/solr-relevancy-function-queries/

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#strdist

Comment: Ya I can get close but still I have a doubt, How can I get the value of `strdist("queryTerm2",fieldName2, JW)` for each document so that I can check later on as `string distance < 5` ?

Comment: You cant directly get the score. Updated my answer to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, it's not possible

Comment: Thanx for info, Is there any possibilty of getting similar facility in upcoming versions of solr?